# CSS dropdown menu with submenu aligning to the right edge of it's parent

Tags: html, css

Here is a very easy example of CSS based dropdown menu: http://jsfiddle.net/V8aL6/

```
    <ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="Return home">Home</a>

    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="About the company">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">The product</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Meet the team</a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="The services we offer">Services</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sevice one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sevice two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sevice three</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Sevice four</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="Our product range">Product</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Small product (one)</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Small product (two)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Small product (three)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Small product (four)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Big product (five)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Big product (six)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Big product (seven)</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Big product (eight)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Enourmous product (nine)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Enourmous product (ten)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Enourmous product (eleven)</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>

        <a href="#" title="Get in touch with us">Contact</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Out-of-hours</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Directions</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But I can't find a solution to align the submenu to the right edge of it's parent, like this:

[image: simple drop-down menu aligned left]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This menu achieves the hiding/showing by modifying the `left` property. All you need is to adapt the CSS-rule which steers the show mechanism for the submenu:

```
#nav li:hover ul{
    left:0;
}
```

instead of aligning it to the left, we want to align it right, so we add `right:0;`. However, if we do not touch the left declaration, the menu will get cut off, so instead of `left:0;` we write `left:auto;` to let the menu expand to it's intrinsic width. To accomodate for the margin of the parent `li`, we add the same amount as negative margin and we are done:

```
#nav li:hover ul{
    left:auto;
    right:0;
    margin-right:-10px;
}
```

[you modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V8aL6/1/)

Comment: Thanks tons...this made no sense to me ...but it solved my problem in my project.

Answer (score 6):

Its better and more clean if you position your list to the right and instead of moving UL out of the screen you could just toggle the display property from none to block.

You will need to make some changes in these rules and add those properties:

```
#nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    right: 0;
}

#nav ul {
    display: none;
}
#nav ul li {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

See my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V8aL6/2/

Comment: altering the `display` property has accessability issues compared to altering the position only.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution should be:

```
#nav ul li ul, #nav ul li:hover ul {
    float:right;
    margin-right:2px; /*optional*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the Bootstrap class `.pull-right` to `<div class='btn-group'`. Should look like below:
`<div class='btn-group pull-right'`

Answer (score -1):

To automatically make dropdowns on the right align right:

```
<script>
// make dropdowns on the right align right, etc, so they don't go off screen
var dropdown_uls = document.querySelectorAll('#nav li ul')
function fix_dropdowns(){
    for (var i=0; i< dropdown_uls.length; i++) {
        var ul = dropdown_uls[i]
        var rect = ul.getBoundingClientRect()
        var body = document.body.getBoundingClientRect()
        if(rect.right > body.right){
            ul.style.left = 'auto'
            ul.style.right = 0
        }
        if(rect.left < body.left){
            ul.style.left = 0
            ul.style.right = 'auto'
        }
    }
}
fix_dropdowns()
addEventListener('resize', fix_dropdowns)
</script>
```

Comment: Why use javascript if you can use css? What happens if a user has javascript turned off in their browser for some reason?

Comment: I have menu items which wrap on to the next line if the screen isn't wide enough, so an item that's on the right may turn into an item on the left depending on browser width. Is there a better way to handle that situation?