# i want left to right drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I have a right menu items  , with a 3 column drop down menu , how can i make the drop down menu open from the left to the right from the beginning of the row ,  not from the item it's belong to?

My code:

```
<div class="container" style="min-height:150px">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top my_nav" role="navigation">
        <header>
            <div class="row" style="max-width: 1200px;
                width: 100%; margin:0 auto">
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                    <a id="logo" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.navbar-header-->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav my_nav1">
                            <li>
                                <a href="index.html">Home </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="about.html">About us </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown active">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Solutions <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="smarthome.html">Smart home system</a>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><a href="elan.html">Elan</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="fibaro.html">Fibaro</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                <li class="divider">        
                                                <li><a href="a-v-controllers.html">A/V distribution systems</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                </li>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#">Surveillance Systems</a>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <a href="#">Avtech</a>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><a href="ip-camera.html">IP Cameras  </a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="cctv-camera.html">CCTV Cameras   </a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="hdtv.html">HDTVI Camera   </a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="nvr.html">N-V recorder  </a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="dvr.html">D-V recorder  </a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="hd-dvr.html">HD DVR   </a></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a href="cameras.html">Elan</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="alarm.html">Alarm system </a>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><a href="jablotron-100.html">Jablotron100 </a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="jablotron-80.html">Jablotron80   </a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="azor.html">azor</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#">Telephone System </a>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><a href="panasonic.html">Panasonic    </a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="samsung.html">Samsung    </a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="kocom.html">   kocom   </a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="comex.html">  comex    </a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a class="#">Electric Doors </a>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <a href="swing.html">Swing</a>
                                                            <ul >
                                                                <li><a href="QUIKO.html">QUIKO     </a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="Vulcan.html">Vulcan     </a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="Calypso.html">Calypso    </a></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <a href="#">Sliding </a>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><a href="quiko-sl.html">QUIKO     </a></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                                <li><a href="cen-v.html">Central vacuum</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.navbar-collapse-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: For opening the dropdown from left to right you can refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519377/css-dropdown-menu-with-submenu-aligning-to-the-right-edge-of-its-parent).

Comment: Thanks a  lot it solved some of my problem