# Right Align Drop Down Menu from an Icon in a Table Header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to open a dropdown menu, aligned to the **right** under an icon, that appears in a `span` on a table header.

This is what I get:

[image: This is what I get]

It aligns naturally **left** under the icon, but I can't find a good way to align it to the **right**.

This is what I actually want:

[image: This is what I want]

[Some suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519377/css-dropdown-menu-with-submenu-aligning-to-the-right-edge-of-its-parent) advise using `right:0;` and position the filter container as `absolute`. This is not good in my case since I want the icon in the table header cell to be aligned to the right of the cell. Setting the container to `absolute` makes it difficult to align the icon in the table header.

I'm looking for a pure CSS solution if possible. The widths of the table cells and the widths of the dropdown menu are **not** fixed, so I cannot align things by specifying "pixels".

```css
table {
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color:#666;
 font-size:12px;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff; 
 background:#eaebec;
 margin:20px;
 border:black 1px solid; 
 border-radius:3px; 
 border-collapse: collapse;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

 
table th {
  width:150px;
}

.context-icon {
    float:right;
    cursor:default;
    color: green;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    
    //position: absolute;
}

.filter {            
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     position: absolute;     
     background-color: #f9f9f9;
     box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     padding: 2px 6px;          
     max-height: 0px;
     z-index: 1000;
     height:auto;
     transition: visibility 200ms, max-height 200ms ease-in-out;
     
     //right:0;
}

.filter-open {
    display: block;
    max-height: 300px;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>first</th>
        <th>
          second
          <span>
            <i class="context-icon fa fa-lg fa-filter">
              <select multiple class="filter filter-open">
                <option >option1</option>
                <option >option2</option>
                <option >option3</option>        
              </select>
            </i>
          </span>
        </th>
        <th>third</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added position relative to i, and right 0px to the select :

```css
i {
  position: relative;
}
i select {
  right: 0px;  
}

table {
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color:#666;
 font-size:12px;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff; 
 background:#eaebec;
 margin:20px;
 border:black 1px solid; 
 border-radius:3px; 
 border-collapse: collapse;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

 
table th {
  width:150px;
}

.context-icon {
    float:right;
    cursor:default;
    color: green;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    
    //position: absolute;
}

.filter {            
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     position: absolute;     
     background-color: #f9f9f9;
     box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     padding: 2px 6px;          
     max-height: 0px;
     z-index: 1000;
     height:auto;
     transition: visibility 200ms, max-height 200ms ease-in-out;
     
     //right:0;
}

.filter-open {
    display: block;
    max-height: 300px;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>first</th>
        <th>
          second
          <span>
            <i class="context-icon fa fa-lg fa-filter">
              <select multiple class="filter filter-open">
                <option >option1</option>
                <option >option2</option>
                <option >option3</option>        
              </select>
            </i>
          </span>
        </th>
        <th>third</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add css below:

```
.filter {
    right: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It moves the dropdown table, but not to the correct position relative to the icon.